# Angular-CLI Error: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'ErrorObservable' from external module but cannot be named

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-cli

After building out an app that is a clone of a working Angular 2 (non-cli) app, I notice several of my files are producing errors (of the same kind) now that the project is built with the Angular-CLI. I'm unclear why these are errors in the CLI version, but not in the other. Is this a Webpack-related issue? Or something to do with how Typescript is processed differently between the two builds? To clarify, the initial app used SystemJS, and the Angular-CLI version uses Webpack. When I say I "built out" the app, I mean I recreated all of the components, directives, modules, routes, etc, that I had in the original app in this clone version. This is the general error message I get (across several files):

> Error: Return type of public method from exported class has or is
>   using name 'ErrorObservable' from external module but cannot be named

And here's an example of a file that's listed as producing this error:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class StreamCountsService {

    private _url: string = "https://api.somesite.com"

    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getCount() {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((response:Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this._errorsHandler);
    }
    _errorsHandler(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
    }
}
```

My Setup:
MacBook Air, OS X El Capitan

Angular-CLI Version
Running the Angular-CLI version 1.0.0-beta.22-1

The full error trace looks like this (edited slightly for privacy):

> vendor.bundle.js:52455 ./src/app/data/stream.service.ts Module build
>   failed: Error:
>   /Users/adds/Documents/abc/abc-cli/cli-abc/src/app/data/stream-assign.service.ts
>   (20,5): Return type of public method from exported class has or is
>   using name 'ErrorObservable' from external module
>   "/Users/adds/Documents/abc/abc-cli/cli-abc/node_modules/rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable"
>   but cannot be named.) at _checkDiagnostics
>   (/Users/adds/Documents/abc/abc-cli/cli-abc/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:115:15)
>   at
>   /Users/adds/Documents/abc/abc-cli/cli-abc/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:140:17
>   @ ./src/app/views/stream/stream-module.ts 25:0-82 @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/index.ts @ ./src/main.ts @ multi
>   main vendor.bundle.js:52455 ./src/app/data/stream-assign.service.ts
>   Module build failed: Error:
>   /Users/adds/Documents/abc/abc-cli/cli-abc/src/app/data/stream-assign-comm.service.ts
>   (20,5): Return type of public method from exported class has or is
>   using name 'ErrorObservable' from external module
>   "/Users/adds/Documents/abc/abc-cli/cli-abc/node_modules/rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable"
>   but cannot be named.) at _checkDiagnostics
>   (/Users/adds/Documents/abc/abc-cli/cli-abc/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:115:15)
>   at
>   /Users/adds/Documents/abc/abc-cli/cli-abc/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:140:17
>   @ ./src/app/views/stream/stream-module.ts 25:0-82 @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ts @ ./src/app/index.ts @ ./src/main.ts @ multi
>   main

Here are my package.json file contents:

```
{
  "name": "cli-ark",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.27",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.29",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.1.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "socket.io": "^1.7.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using:

```
return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
```

if you are using rxjs > rc.5 use:

```
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
```

instead of:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

this is unnecessary

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately, no difference. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Just added my package.json file above. Re: rxjs, I am using:

 "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",

Comment: Ah, just tried it on one of the problem files, and my 15 errors reduced to 14. So this may be it. I'll keep applying across the other files. Thanks!

Comment: Yup! This was the needed fix. It's still strange to me that this wasn't causing errors in the original Angular 2 app, but it did with this Angular-CLI version. Any insight on that? Either way, resolved now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After rx update to 5+ version, you should use

> ErrorObservable

instead of

> throw

Your code should update from:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
...  
this.somethingReturnObservable.get()
  .filter( val => val*2)
  .do((val) => {
    // do something for example
  })
  .switchMap(trans => Observable.throw( 'some error' ))
  .catch( (er, c) => dosomething);
```

To:

```
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/errorObservable';
import { switchMap, tap, catchError, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
this.somethingReturnObservable.get()
  .pipe(
    filter( val => val*2)
    tap( (val) => {// do something for example} ),
    switchMap( trans => ErrorObservable.create( 'some error' ) ),
    catchError( (er, c) => dosomething);
  );
```